# Rename [voting-registration] to [voter-registration]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-renaming

Please rename [voting-registration](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-registration) to [voter-registration](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voter-registration).

Voter registration is the more common and recognized term.

Using Google search:

| Search terms | Results |
| --- | --- |
| "voter registration" -"voting registration" | About 32,400,000 results |
| "voting registration" -"voter registration" | About 238,000 results |

Comment: Can you please provide a source for voter-registration is more common?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica [Google Ngram confirms this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=voter+registration%2C+voting+registration), so I've implemented the change.

Comment: @JJJ I think you might have done the opposite of what you intended, for me voter-registration is a synonym of voting-registration now (though it’s possible this is just a bug on my device)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica yea, it can take 10-30 minutes for the system to fully implement it.